# Possible to indent the second line of url

Tags: css

i was trying to indent a second line of a url so it is flush with the first letter of the sentence.  Is this possible ? I know you can use `<ul>`but I was having trouble with it as it inherited small text and bullet points from the main .css file.

look here http://test.darkrome.com/official-vatican-museum-partnership on the bottom right - 3 bullet points under Exclusive Vatican experiences - the text is  not in line

*edit, test site updated with ul - text is in line with ul but bullet points squashed

Comment: The example is not a ul. With a ul, all text is aligned at left in the same line

Comment: yes exactly, I was using a ul but it started to inherit from a parent css and the bullet points didn't match up (they were all cramped due to the font in the parent being a lot smaller)

Comment: And if you overwrite the css?

Comment: i couldnt over right the css from the main file - it had small font in the main css for a (which is the hyperlink ) so when i used a i got a small font even if i specified a large font.

Comment: Ok, I just need see the code, and look for a solution. Can you put the html and css (final css, inherited too) in your question?

Comment: take a look at the page now... i added a ul near the bottom, can you see the way its all on top of each other ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78293/discussion-between-pabgaran-and-aindriu).

Comment: Why not use the good old table layout? http://plnkr.co/edit/oMEu93BsgZg0LValZ7uZ?p=preview

Comment: you are using <p> instead of <ul><li>.. if you use, it will work fine

Comment: With your `<ul>`..`<li>`..you just need bottom margins on the `<li>`'s.

Comment: can i adjust the bottom margin ?

Comment: You can do pretty much anything you want stylewise in your css. @Amit 's answer is the compliant way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access to DOM, i think that the best way is add a class to ul:

```
<ul class="myclass">
    ...
</ul>
```

And then, in css:

```
ul.myclass li a { float: none;}
```

If you can't access to css files, you could put style inline:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a style="float: none">...</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thus, you don't interfere with other ul's on your page.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `<ul> <li> ...</li></ul>` instead of `<p><a>...</a></p>` for unordered list. If you use `<ul>..</ul>` output will look like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fyyh72dt/)**

CSS:

```
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

**Edit:**

I tried like this and its working fine:

```
    <div class="subvmtext"> Dark Rome has exclusive one-of-a-kind tours to make your Vatican experience most memorable
 <ul>
  <li> <a style="color: #000000" href="/vatican-tours/vatican-breakfast"> IP Early Breakfast inside the Vatican Museums with Sistine Chapel and St. Peter's Basilica. </a></li>
  <li> <a style="color: #000000" 
    href="/tours/vatican-tours/vatican-sistine-express-and-st-peters"> Express Sistine Chapel, St. Peter's Basilica, and Vatican Crypt Tour.</a> </li>
  <li> <a style="color: #000000" 
href="/tours/vatican-tours/extended-vatican-museum-tour-with-bramante-staircase"> Extended Sistine Chapel Vatican Museums Tour with Bramante 
   Staircase and St. Peter's.</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i am using that but its all squashed

Comment: add this to your css. `padding: 10px 0;`

Comment: float: none; can i add that to ul